# How to repair a broken package?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

My libboost package is broken. I don't know how to fix it.
I tried:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and it was the result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-chrono1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-date-time1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-exception1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-filesystem1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-graph-parallel1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-graph1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-iostreams1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-locale1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-log1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-math1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-mpi1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-program-options1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-python1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-random1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-regex1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-serialization1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-signals1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-system1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-test1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-thread1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-timer1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-wave1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost1.54-all-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Then I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -f libboost1.54-dev
```

and it was the result:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-atomic1.53.0 libboost-context1.53.0 libboost-graph1.53.0 libboost-locale1.53.0 libboost-math1.53.0 libboost-python1.53.0
  libboost-random1.53.0 libboost-signals1.53.0 libboost-test1.53.0 libboost-timer1.53.0 libboost-wave1.53.0 libboost1.53-tools-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  libboost1.54-doc libboost-coroutine.54-dev libboost-log.54-dev xsltproc doxygen default-jdk fop
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libboost1.54-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
24 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 101 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 320270 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libboost1.54-dev (from .../libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/quickbook', which is also in package libboost1.53-tools-dev 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And this is the result of sudo apt-get check:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-chrono1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-date-time1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-exception1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-filesystem1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-graph-parallel1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-graph1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-iostreams1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-locale1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-log1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-math1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-mpi1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-program-options1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-python1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-random1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-regex1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-serialization1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-signals1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-system1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-test1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-thread1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-timer1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost-wave1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not installed
 libboost1.54-all-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

and the result of

```
apt-cache policy libboost1.54-all-dev libboost-wave1.54-dev libboost-python1.54-dev
```

is:

```
libboost1.54-all-dev:
  Installed: 1.54.0-2ubuntu3
  Candidate: 1.54.0-2ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 1.54.0-2ubuntu3 0
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libboost-wave1.54-dev:
  Installed: 1.54.0-2ubuntu3
  Candidate: 1.54.0-2ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 1.54.0-2ubuntu3 0
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libboost-python1.54-dev:
  Installed: 1.54.0-2ubuntu3
  Candidate: 1.54.0-2ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 1.54.0-2ubuntu3 0
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

What should I do to repair libboost package?

Comment: Search the package you need to install, in [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) matching to your System version. Then try to install the package appropriate to your system version.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libboost1.54-all-dev libboost-wave1.54-dev libboost-python1.54-dev`?

Comment: @Braiam add its output to question.

Comment: Did you remove `libboost1.53-tools-dev` as said in my answer?

Comment: I tired apt-get purge -f and the result was same as apt-get autoremove

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just encountered the same problem and libboost1.54-dev just would not overwrite libboost1.53-dev. My goal was to install libboost1.54-all-dev, but all the other packages depended on libboost1.54-dev and that would not install.

So I went to packages.ubuntu.com and searched for libboost1.54-dev for saucy ([link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libboost1.54-dev)) and downloaded the file.

Once the deb file was in my computer I had to install it while forcing it to overwrite with the following line:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

after that just doing

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

solved the issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `libboost1.53-tools-dev` then try again.

```
sudo apt-get purge -f libboost1.53-tools-dev
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If no error appears here, continue,

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

otherwise **edit your question** and add the result of `sudo apt-get check`.

Comment: again the same error.